# How do I combine groups with low number of observations into a newly defined group – for bar plot graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataset based on agronomic data of crop species. The data contains a count of the number of observations (popularity) of each crop species.

**My goal** is to construct a bar plot of the most popular species, BUT I am also interested in visualizing the combined number of species that are not as popular. For this, I would like to combine the observational counts of each of the underrepresented species and add it to a newly defined group called "other_crops". It is the idea that I can then plot a chart that shows not only the most popular but also the 'remaining' underrepresented crop species.

*Here is what I have so far:*

```
plotdata_crops <- database_crops %>% 
  group_by(CROP.SPECIES) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(pct = (count/sum(count))) %>%
  mutate(CROP.SPECIES_simplified = ifelse(count < 10, "other", CROP.SPECIES)) %>% 
  group_by(CROP.SPECIES_simplified)
```

*which give me this table:*

[image]

But **the issue** is that when I plot it I get strange marks in the bar for the other category for each of the individual crop species.

```
ggplot(data = plotdata_crops,                          
       aes(x = reorder(CROP.SPECIES_simplified, count), 
           y = count)) +                             
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           fill = my_col_single) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(round(pct*100, 1),"%")), size=3, vjust = -2) +
  labs(x = "Crop species",                       
       y = "Number") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1), legend.position = "none")  +
  ylim(c(0, 120)) +
  labs(title = "Distribution of annual crop species grown in association with trees",
       subtitle = paste("n (study sites) = ", n_individual_study_sites),
       caption = paste("Based on data from the database"),
       x = "Crop species")
```

[image]

Here is a little subset of the 'raw' data

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~ID.P, ~STUDY.NO, ~ID.S, ~...4,                                                                                                                                                                                ~AUTHOR,                                                                                                                                   ~TITLE,     ~STUDY.LOC.SPEC, ~STUDY.LOC.COUNTRY, ~STUDY.LOC.SPEC.COORDS, ~...10,       ~CROP.SPECIES,
     99,        NA,    10,    NA,                                                                       "Pardon, P., Reubens, B., Reheul, D., Mertens, J., Frenne, P. d., Coussement, T., Janssens, P. and Verheyen, K.",                                         "Trees increase soil organic carbon and nutrient availability in temperate agroforestry systems", "Several locations",          "Belgium",           "Steenhuize",     NA,          "Zea mays",
     87,        37,     1,    NA,                                                                                                                                                    "Oelbermann, M. and Voroney, R. P.",                    "Carbon and nitrogen in a temperate agroforestry system: using stable isotopes as a tool to understand soil dynamics",           "Ontario",           "Canada",               "Guelph",     NA, "Triticum aestivum",
     99,        NA,     9,    NA,                                                                       "Pardon, P., Reubens, B., Reheul, D., Mertens, J., Frenne, P. d., Coussement, T., Janssens, P. and Verheyen, K.",                                         "Trees increase soil organic carbon and nutrient availability in temperate agroforestry systems", "Several locations",          "Belgium",              "Herzele",     NA,    "Lolium perenne",
     90,        NA,     2,    NA,                                                                             "Oelbermann, M., Voroney, R. P., Thevathasan, N. V., Gordon, A. M., Kass, D. C. L. and Schlonvoigt, A. M.",                            "Soil carbon dynamics and residue stabilization in a Costa Rican and southern Canadian alley cropping system",           "Ontario",           "Canada",               "Guelph",     NA,       "Glycine max",
     47,        NA,     2,    NA,                                                                                           "Gruenewald, H., Brandt, B. K. V., Schneider, B. U., Bens, O., Kendzia, G. and Huttl, R. F.",                                            "Agroforestry systems for the production of woody biomass for energy transformation purposes", "Several locations",          "Germany",            "Helmstedt",     NA,      "Lupinus spp.",
    166,        NA,     3,    NA,                                                                                                           "Tom Staton, Tom D. Breeze, Richard J. Walters, Jo Smith, Robbie D. Girling",                                      "Productivity, biodiversity trade-offs, and farm income in an agroforestry versus an arable system", "Several locations",   "United Kingdom",      "Cambridgeshire ",     NA, "Triticum aestivum",
     82,        34,     1,    NA,                                                                                                                                                   "Mungai, N. W. and Motavalli, P. P.",                                        "Litter quality effects on soil carbon and nitrogen dynamics in temperate alley cropping systems",          "Missouri",              "USA",     "Trenton Missouri",     NA,     "Poa trivialis",
     50,        NA,     1,    NA,                                                                                                                                        "Huber, J. A., Matiu, M. and Hulsbergen, K. J.",     "First-rotation growth and stand structure dynamics of tree species in organic and conventional short-rotation agroforestry systems",           "Bavaria",          "Germany",             "Scheyern",     NA,   "Helianthus spp.",
     94,        NA,     9,    NA, "Graves, A. R., Burgess, P. J., Palma, J. H. N., Herzog, F., Moreno, G., Bertomeu, M., Dupraz, C., Liagre, F., Keesman, K., van der Werf, W., de Nooy, A. K. and van den Briel, J. P.", "Development and application of bio-economic modelling to compare silvoarable, arable, and forestry systems in three European countries", "Several locations",            "Spain",  "St Maria del Paramo",     NA,   "Helianthus spp.",
     97,        NA,     1,    NA,                                                                           "Pardon, P., Mertens, J., Reubens, B., Reheul, D., Coussement, T., Elsen, A., Nelissen, V. and Verheyen, K.",   "Juglans regia (walnut) in temperate arable agroforestry systems: Effects on soil characteristics, arthropod diversity and crop yield",       "Tielt-Winge",          "Belgium",          "Tielt-Winge",     NA,   "Hordeum vulgare"
  )
```

*I'm sure this is an easy one, but I haven't been able to solve it even after spending a few hours scrolling through the internet.*

Comment: count is based on CROP.SPECIES and not CROP.SPECIES_simplified you need to `summarize()` by  CROP.SPECIES_simplified

Comment: You do a `group_by` but forget to do a `summarise`. What you want is to add `%>% summarise(count = sum(count))` after your `group_by`. That way, you 'collapse' the other rows together

Comment: Another thing you could use to create the 'other' group is [fct_lump](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_lump.html)

Comment: Thanks @Mike and @Bas for these suggestions.  I managed by simply adding a `%>% summarise(count = sum(count))` – so simple LOL! :-) Enjoy your week etc.

Comment: I got some inspiration from Cedrics Scherer's blog. https://www.cedricscherer.com/2021/07/05/a-quick-how-to-on-labelling-bar-graphs-in-ggplot2/